# salesforce rule to display selected values in picklist on selection of another picklist

Tags: salesforce, picklist

I am new in salesforce and learning it.
There is a task which i want to perform, Description is as follows:

I've created a custom object **Property** and few fields for this object.
There are two picklist type of fields for this object **Country** and **City**.

**Country** field contains following values: United States, United Kingdom, India, China, Japan and etc.

**City** field contains following values: New York, Los Angeles, Glasgow, London, Tokyo, Beijing, New Delhi, Dehradun etc.

What i want to do is when user selects a specific value in **Country** field only related **City** should display for selection in **City** field.

For example: If user selects United States in **Country** field then only New York and Los Angeles should be displayed for selection in **City** field or If user selects United Kingdom in **Country** field then only Glasgow, Manchester and London should be displayed for selection in **City** field and then user will select one value from available **City** value.

Thanks in advance, Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field dependices will do this for you

Comment: Thanks, I've created dependent picklist.